# Implementation of Orthogonal Camera in C#

Tags: c#, raytracing

I'm making a simple ray tracer and right now I'm trying to make a simple orthogonal view showing a sphere but instead of a red circle on a black background I get a red rectangle...

In my sphere class I have a method for checking if a ray hits a sphere:

```
    public bool IntersectsRay(Ray ray) //c -> origin, R -> radius, o - origin ray, 
    //d - direction ray 
    {
        Vector3 d = ray.direction;
        Vector3 o = ray.origin;
        Vector3 c = origin;
        double R = radius;

        double A = d.DotVector(d); //d^2
        double B = 2 * d.DotVector(o.MinusVector(c)); //2d(o - c)
        double C = (o.MinusVector(c)).DotVector(o.MinusVector(c)) - radius * radius; //(o - c)(o - c) - R^2

        double delta = B * B - 4 * A * C;

        if (delta < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no intersection points");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("delta is equal to: {0}", delta);

            double t1 = (-B + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / 2 * A;
            double t2 = (-B - Math.Sqrt(delta)) / 2 * A;

            if (t1.Equals(t2))
            {
                Vector3 P1 = o.PlusVector(d.MultiplyByScalar((float)t1));

                Console.WriteLine("P0: ({0}, {1}, {2})", P1.x, P1.y, P1.z);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Vector3 P1 = o.PlusVector(d.MultiplyByScalar((float)t1));
                Vector3 P2 = o.PlusVector(d.MultiplyByScalar((float)t2));

                Console.WriteLine("P1: ({0}, {1}, {2}), P2: ({3}, {4}, {5})", P1.x, P1.y, P1.z, P2.x, P2.y, P2.z);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Orthogonal camera class:

```
public class CamOrthogonal
{
    public Bitmap BM;
    private float pixelWidth;
    private float pixelHeight;
    private float centerPixelX;
    private float centerPixelY;
    private bool intersection;

    public CamOrthogonal()
    {
        this.BM = new Bitmap(240, 240, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    }

    public CamOrthogonal(Img IMG)
    {
        this.BM = IMG.BM;
    }

    public void render(Sphere S)
    {
        pixelWidth = 2.0f / BM.Width;
        pixelHeight = 2.0f / BM.Height;

        for (int i = 0; i < BM.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < BM.Height; j++)
            {
                centerPixelX = -1.0f + (i + 0.5f) * pixelWidth;
                centerPixelY = 1.0f - (j + 0.5f) * pixelHeight;

                //Ray ray = new Ray(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(centerPixelX, centerPixelX, 0));
                Ray ray = new Ray(new Vector3(centerPixelX, centerPixelX, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 1));

                /* if (Plane_or_Sphere is Plane)
                {
                    intersection = ((Plane)Plane_or_Sphere).IntersectsRay(ray);
                }
                else if (Plane_or_Sphere is Sphere)
                {
                    intersection = ((Sphere)Plane_or_Sphere).IntersectsRay(ray);
                } */

                intersection = S.IntersectsRay(ray);

                if (intersection == true)
                {
                    this.BM.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Red);
                }
                else 
                {
                    this.BM.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Black);
                }
            }
        }
        this.BM.Save("/Users/Aleksy/Desktop/RT_IMG.jpg");
    }
}
```

An then, in my main class I have:

```
CamOrthogonal CAM = new CamOrthogonal();
Sphere S = new Sphere(0, 0, -10, (float)0.1); //origin - x,y,z & radius
CAM.render(S);
```

And what I get is that red rectangle. Where did I make the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have:

`double t1 = (-B + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / 2 * A;`

In C#, this is evaluated according to the [operator precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#multiplicative-operators), which state that `*` and `/` are multiplicative operators. It also says:

> The operators within each section share the same precedence level.

Therefore, `*` and `/` have equal precedence; they are evaluated left to right. Therefore, your statement is getting evaluated like so:

`double t1 = (((-B + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / 2) * A);`

However, what you actually want to solve the quadratic equation is this:

`double t1 = (-B + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * A);`

...and the same for `t2`.

EDIT

Also, your hit conditions are incorrect:

```
if (t1.Equals(t2))
{
   Vector3 P1 = o.PlusVector(d.MultiplyByScalar((float)t1));
   Console.WriteLine("P0: ({0}, {1}, {2})", P1.x, P1.y, P1.z);
   return true;
}
else
{
   Vector3 P1 = o.PlusVector(d.MultiplyByScalar((float)t1));
   Vector3 P2 = o.PlusVector(d.MultiplyByScalar((float)t2));
   Console.WriteLine("P1: ({0}, {1}, {2}), P2: ({3}, {4}, {5})", P1.x, P1.y, P1.z, P2.x, P2.y, P2.z);
   return true;
}
```

The ray actually hits if `t1 >= 0` or `t2 >= 0`. In that case, the intersection point is given by whichever `t` is smallest (but still `>= 0`).